# use apply() to execute array of setTimeouts with args

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

I need to be able to build an array of anonymous functions that execute setTimeout with unique arguments per function.  The following code has already been proposed, and works, on SO, but it only deals with immediate execution of the setTimeout.  It does not explain how one can accumulate a collection of setTimeout functions to an array, with each setTimeout function having its own closure that defines a unique variable to be used in the execution of the setTimeout.

This is what exists already on SO:

```
var strings = [ "hello", "world" ];
for(var i=0;i<strings.length;i++) {
    setTimeout(
        (function(s) {
            return function() {
                alert(s);
            }
        })(strings[i]), 1000);
}
```

This is one of many permutations of what I have tried:

```
var strings = [ "hello", "world" ];
var func_array = [];
for (var i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    func_array.push(function() {
      setTimeout(
          (function(s) {
              return function() {
                  alert(s);
              }
          })(strings[i]), 1000);
    });
}
```

When apply() is called on func_array, the strings[i] value is the same for each call, i.e. the final member of the strings array.

Another attempt: here we make the function that gets pushed onto func_array self-executing in order to scope the strings[i] variable correctly.  However, apply() sees only 'undefined' since the function has already executed.

```
var strings = [ "hello", "world" ];
var func_array = [];
for (var i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    func_array.push(function(s) {
      setTimeout(
          (function(s) {
              return function() {
                  alert(s);
              }
          })(s), 1000);
    }(strings[i]));
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind). It becomes much simpler than it actually is.

```
var strings = [ "hello", "world" ];
var func_array = [];
for (var i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    var fn = function(string){
        return setTimeout(function(){ alert(string) } ,1000);
    };
    func_array.push(fn.bind(this, strings[i]));
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue.  Nice, clean, and pure JS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want.

```js
var strings = ["hello", "world"];
var func_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    (function (s) {
        var func = function () {
            alert("String is " + s);
        }
        
        var futureFunc = function () {
            setTimeout(func, 1000);
        }
        
        func_array.push(futureFunc);
    } (strings[i]));
}

func_array[0]()
func_array[1]()
```

Comment: It works. Yours and the answer from jkris both do the job.  Which one you go with is a matter of coding style and how it fits within the application you might be working with.  Thanks!